# Не удаляет запись с помощью Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

Всем привет. Какая то магическая ситуация. Есть таблица users в проекте на Laravel. Не отрабатывается удаление с помощью Ajax. Самое интересное - добавление записи отрабатывает нормально без перезагрузки. Удаление - происходит после перезагрузки страницы. Дебагер Laravel дает The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.
и ошибку The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. а консоль просто выдает error
Route

```
Route::delete('/users/{id}','Admin\UserController@destroy')
```

Controller

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
       User::where('id',$id)->delete();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

View

```
  <form action="">

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mx-3 delete" data-id="{{$user->id}} ">Delete   </button>

    </form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
$('.delete').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let u = $(this).data('id');
            confirm('Are you sure want to delete?');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'delete',
                url: "/users/"+u,
                data: {'id': u},
                success: function () {
                    $("tr" + u).remove();
                    // console.log('ok')
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log('error' + e.toString())
                },

            })
        })
```

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1000177/256824

Comment: Попробовал-выдает ту же ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример отправки формы по AJAX для [удаления сущности из БД](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#method-field).

**Маршрут**

```
// Для удобства лучше использовать именованный маршрут.
Route::delete('/users/{id}','Admin\UserController@destroy')->name('user.delete');

// Еще лучше так:
Route::resource('users', 'Admin\UserController')
  ->names([
    'destroy' => 'user.delete'
    // ... другие имена
  ]);
```

**Форма с AJAX запросом**

```html
<!--
  Указываем параметр для маршрута `DELETE`.
-->

<form id="user_delete" method="post">
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')

  <ul>
  @foreach ($users as $user)
    <li>
      {{ $user->name }}
      <button type="submit"
        onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete?');"
        formaction="{{ route('user.delete', $user) }}"
      >Удалить</button>
    </li>
  @endforeach
  </ul>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user_delete:first").submit(function(event) {
      // Отменяем стандартное поведение формы.
      event.preventDefault();

      // Собираем данные с формы.
      // Здесь будут все поля у которых есть `name`,
      // включая метод `_method` и `_token`
      var data = new FormData(this);

      // Берем `formaction` с текущей нажатой кнопки.
      // Можете выбрать другой способ,
      // для подстановки URL и указания ID.
      var action = $(document.activeElement).attr('formaction');

      // Отправляем запрос.
      $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: action,
        cache: false, // запрошенные страницы не будут закешированы браузером.
        data: data, // data: data - больше ничего тут не надо!
        dataType: 'json', // чтобы jQuery распарсил `success` ответ.
        processData: false, // чтобы jQuery не обрабатывал отправляемые данные.
        contentType: false, // чтобы jQuery не передавал в заголовке поле `Content-Type` совсем.
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    })
  });
</script>
```