# Laravel удаление модели из БД

Tags: php, laravel

Не удаляет запись из БД.

**Роут**

```
Route::get('/product/delete/{$id}','ProductsController@delete')->name('delete.product');
```

**Контроллер**

```
protected function delete($id) {
  $product = Product::find($id);
  $product->delete();
  return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

**Вьюха**

```html
@foreach ($products as $product)
<div class="product card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="product__name card-title">
      <a href="{{route('view_product',$product->id)}}">
        <span>{{$product->name}}</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <a href="{{route('delete.product',$product->id)}}"> Удалить товар</a>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Выкидывает на страницу Error 404. Хотя вроде делаю все правильно.
Подскажите что не так!

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1000213/256824

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас нет именного роута 'index' в web.php

- Возможно вам подойдет лучше 
  `return back();`
- Или попробуйте указать жестко url 
  `return redirect('/');`
- Или создайте в web.php именной роут 'index'

Comment: У меня уже был именованный роут 'index'. По пробовал `return back();` и жестко указать `return redirect('/');` не помогло.

Comment: Попробуйте еще такой вариант, изменть эту запись 
```{{route('delete.product',$product->id)}} ```
На такую:
```{{route('delete.product',[$product->id])}}```

Comment: @ n1xez  не помогло(

Comment: Метод контроллера должен быть публичным 
```protected``` замените на ```public```