# Как сделать подтверждение удаление пользователя?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

***мой контролер***

```
 public function destroy ($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user_role =User_roles::find($id);
        $user->delete();
        $user_role->delete();
        return redirect('users');
    }
}
```

***форма удаления***

```
<form method="GET" action="user/destroy/{{ $u->id }}" id="form_{{ $loop->index }}">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" onclick="document.getElementById('form_{{ $loop->index }}').submit()"></i>
                        </form>
```

> Нужно чтобы когда админ нажал на кнопку удалить он увидел
>   подтверждение удаление еcли нажмет да то пользователь удалиться если
>   нет то окно закроется

Comment: Что-то такое? `onclick="if(confirm('удаляем?')){document.getElementById('form_{{ $loop->index }}').submit();}"`

Comment: сразу после нажатия пользователь удоляется

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1000293/256824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно заюзать готовую библиотеку [SweetAlert](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/), она довольно проста в изучении и красиво делает свое дело.

```js
$('.form_delete').on('submit', function(){
swal({
  title: "Внимание",
  text: "Действительно желаете удалить пользователя?",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
  confirmButtonText: "Да, удалить!",
  cancelButtonText: "Отменить",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm) {
  if (isConfirm) {
    $.ajax({...}) // отправляем аякс и на стороне сервера удаляем запись
  } else {
    swal.close(); // закрываем окно
  }
});
});
```

Comment: а куда добавлять тот код который вы скинули?

Comment: я так понимаю что с javascript вы явно не дружите?

Comment: мы с ней даже не на ВЫ

Comment: сможете помочь или материал с инструкцией скинуть?

Comment: ну для того чтобы реализовать то что вам нужно, вы должны иметь хотя бы базовые знания javascript и jquery

Comment: для меня лучшим учебником был https://learn.javascript.ru/

Answer (score 2):

```js
if(confirm('Удалить пользователя?')) {
  // тут обращение к серверу на удаление пользователя..
  alert('Пользователь удалён');
} else {
  // закрыть окно
}
```

Comment: Это в контроллер или в форму ?

Comment: Этот код должен быть сделан через JS, далее в случае истины вы отправляете ajax запрос на ваш "контроллёр", в котором обрабатываете его. ИД пользователе, думаю, лучше передавать через параметр.