# Не отрабатывает update Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

Возникла проблема с `CRUD` `ajax`. Не отрабатывает скорее всего метод `update`.Выдает следующую ошибку:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Controller

```
 public function update(Request $request,$id)
    {

        $user=User::find($id);
        $user ->update([
//            'id'=>$request->id,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ]);
//        $user->update($request->all());
        return response()->json('ok');
    }
```

```js
$('#userEdit').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let name = $("#editname").val();
  let email = $("#editemail").val();
  let id = $('#userid').val();
  let password = $('#editpassword').val();
  let action = $(this).attr('formaction');
   confirm(id);
  $.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: action,
      data: {
          'id': id,
          'name': name,
          'email': email,
          'password': password
      },
      success: function () {
          console.log('ok');
      },
      error: function (e) {
          console.log('error' + e);
      }
})
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="editUser" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="" method="post" id="EditUser">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="userid" value="{{$user->id}}">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-title form-control">
                    <h4>Edit user</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <span id="form_output"></span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name"> name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="editname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name"> email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="editemail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text"> password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="editpassword"
                               autocomplete="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit" id="userEdit"
                           formaction="{{route('users.update',$user)}}" class="btn btn-info">
                    {{--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>--}}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Пишет ошибка что дублирующее вхождение, то есть вы пытаетесь обновить запись на то значение, которое уже имеется в базе, а именно в каком то из полей где стоит primarykey или ограничение по уникальности. Схему таблицы можно в студию,в которую делаете запись?

Comment: Добавил миграцию

Comment: `$table->string('email')->unique();` вот у вас уникальное значение в базе должно быть с таким e-mail, а вы видимо пытаетесь вставить повторно его или аналогичное

Comment: да но мне нужно обновить запись.

Comment: 1) проверьте, что значения поля e-mail не дублируется
или
2) Уберите уникальность этого поля

Comment: убрал unique ошибку не выдает но и не обновляет user

Comment: В этом ответе посмотрите, как AJAX формируется https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1000182/256824

Comment: А почему POST? RESOURCE ROUTE для обновления предлагает put|patch .